# React filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new and studying React.
I am trying to make a search filter, I followed the youtube and made a function. But it did not work with the error "Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return". I have done everything. It still did not work.
Anyone help please.

```
          const boards = this.state.boards.filter((board)=>{
                if(this.state.search == null)
                    return board
                else if(board.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) || board.content.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())){
                    return board
                }
              }).map(board=>{
                return(
                    <tr key = {board.idx}>
                    <td> {board.idx} </td>
                    <td><button  className="btn btn-link" onClick = {() => this.BoardDetail(board.idx)}> {board.title}</button></td>
                    <td> {board.insertTime} </td>
                    <td> {board.updateTime} </td>
                    <td> {board.viewCnt} </td>
                </tr>
                )
                })
```

Comment: please add the initial state also to question

Comment: If both the conditions inside the callback failed, then it will return undefined, which can cause error.

Answer (score 1):

Making assumptions here, since as user Mohit Kushwaha stated, the initial state is necessary to debug properly.

Your filter functions are returning the wrong "type" of value.  if you look at [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters), you'll notice that the callback asks for a function that will return a `true` or `false` value.

> callbackFn
>
> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the
> array. Return a value that coerces to `true` to keep the
> element, or to `false` otherwise.

What this means is that instead of returning `board` in your filter function, you should return `true`/`false`.  In the example below I'm returning `true` when I think you are trying to keep something in the array - for example when the `this.state.search` matches your board's title or content, and `false` when you want to remove it, for example if there is no match (again making assumptions - you should really try to formulate your question with as much relevant detail):

```js
const boards = this.state.boards.filter((board) => {
  if(this.state.search == null) {
    // If there is no search value, don't filter anything
    return true 
  } else if (
    board.title.toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) || 
    board.content.toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
  ) {
    // If the search string matches, keep the `board` 
    return true 
  } else {
    // If there is a search string and it does not match, filter out the `board` 
    return false 
  }
})
.map(/* ...the rest of your map function */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on `filter` function: not all the paths return something (I mean, on internal `if` you forgot to add final `else` case).

But you could make things more easy. Infact, considering that `filter` function wants a boolean condition (to filter `this.state.boards` elements) you could write something like:

```
const boards = this.state.boards.filter((board)=>{
                return this.state.search === null || (board.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) || board.content.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()))
              }).map(board=>{
                return(
                    <tr key = {board.idx}>
                    <td> {board.idx} </td>
                    <td><button  className="btn btn-link" onClick = {() => this.BoardDetail(board.idx)}> {board.title}</button></td>
                    <td> {board.insertTime} </td>
                    <td> {board.updateTime} </td>
                    <td> {board.viewCnt} </td>
                </tr>
                )
                })
```

Just put your conditions in `or` and error disappears.

Comment: @john no problem. Happy coding =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `filter`, you can try using `reduce` that will be bit easy like following:

```
const boards = this.state.boards.reduce((acc,board) => {
      if(this.state.search == null)
                    return acc.concat(board);
      else if(board.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) || board.content.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())){
                    return acc.concat(board);
           }
           //else return acc
           return acc;
    },[])
    .map(/* ...the rest of your map function */)
```